# Restore system attribute

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, database

I've disabled the weight attribute in the database (is_required=0) because we didn't need it, so we didn't have to fill it in at every product. Quite stupid, because now we want to enable table rate shipping weight vs destination. Obviously this doesn't work, because it can't do anything with the weight attribute because it didn't recognize it anymore.

Yesterday I've changed is_required to 1, restored the defaults but that was messing up my products, the attribute sets were gone, 404 when opening a product in frontend. Restored it with my DB backup.

Do you guys have any idea how to fix this, or a workaround so I can use the weight vs destination shipping?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, **never** edit the database directly, it's recipe for a disaster. In this case, you have no choice as you need to restore a working version of your site, but please make a backup and run the following carefully.

1. Restore "is_required" to 1.
2. You will need to populate the weight value for all the existing products.

`DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity_decimal WHERE attribute_id = WEIGHT_ATTRIBUTE_ID_HERE;`

`INSERT INTO catalog_product_entity_decimal (entity_type_id, store_id, attribute_id, entity_id, value) SELECT PRODUCT_ENTITY_TYPE_ID_HERE, 0, WEIGHT_ATTRIBUTE_ID_HERE, entity_id, 1 FROM catalog_product_entity;`

3. Go to `Manage Attributes > Attributes`, then set a default value for `weight` so you don't get bothered every time you create a new product.
4. Re-index `Product Attributes` in `System > Index Management`

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new attribute called weight as text field from admin.
GO to admin->Catalog->attributes->fill out required attribute properties and frontend properties.Then add it in default attribute set.

Then you can retrieve your attribute again.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Then I have to delete the weight attribute first?

Comment: Yes just go to table eav_attribute and find attribute id = 80

Comment: "The attribute weight is reserved by system", so it is not going to work :(

Comment: ya ..i know... for that you need to create by something different name like weight2.because it was system attribute thats why it is reserved.

Comment: then ..go to attribute set and add the newly created weight2 attribute into default set ..in general group.

Comment: I know that, but magento is searching for the weight attribute, so naming it weight2 does not make any difference at all, I cant make my table rate shipping work with that attribute...

Comment: then...you will need to create a separate module to work it out.

Comment: And this is what you called an answer? why not type it just in one line, I am dealing with this problem for a couple of hours, I know how to use google, I know it was stupid, and I'm searching for a fix or workaround, your "answer" is quite obvious, like I didn't try that myself